An object's colour and its relation to light
I know that an object (say, a block of red colour) appears red because white light from the light bulb or sun shines on it, and the block absorbs all the other wavelengths of light except that corresponding to the red region of the visible spectrum. It reflects that red wavelength and hits our retina, so we see it as a red-coloured object. (I've started with the topic of black body radiation, and I've heard something surface being black and absorbing all the wavelengths and reflecting none, and from there, this thing occurred to me.) 
If we take that block and cover it with some object which has blue pigments, then it would reflect blue and absorb all others, so now the block would appear blue, not red. But viewing it from the atomic level, why should it be that the light only interacts with the surface atoms and not the atoms and molecules beyond (or behind) the surface atoms, like the red part of the block? Because light is made up of photons and atoms with electrons, and both are quantum objects. So, the light should be able to interact with the atoms beyond the blue covering and give us red light, too (can quantum tunneling be applied over here?). 
So, what is the reason behind all this? Or, how am I mistaken in understanding all these?

If the coating of blue color is sufficiently thin, sure, some blue and some red will be reflected. Opaque coatings are just too thick.

Transmission coefficient or tunneling through potential barrier (we can imagine photon absorption as some sort of potential barrier wrt reflection, though strictly speaking it's not) probability has form $$ \large T\approx \frac{\alpha}{e^ {2\beta L}} \tag 1 $$
when $T\ll 1$, here $L$ is potential barrier width. In your case $L$ would be blue pigment layer width for a red wavelength range photon.
Now actually photon needs to tunnel through the barrier until it reaches red color layer, be reflected and tunnel blue layer once again while going back to the surface. So in (1) you need to double barrier width, like $$T\approx \frac{\alpha}{e^ {4\beta L}} \tag 2$$
Depending on how much you will add blue dyes to the first layer, due to exponential decay ($4\times$ the layer width) of tunneling probability, it would be nearly impossible for a red frequency range photon to reach your eyes.
That being said there are specific coatings which reflects back $50\%$ of incoming light and pass through other half of beam photons. This means that of target frequency range photon has $T=0.5$ transmission coefficient. But this is usually done by controlling very well optical coating width, for it being comparable to the photon wave-length or by controlling dyes and imperfections weak concentrations in the glass.

Thankyou. Are you talking about quantum tunneling over here?

Yes, transmission coefficient is used to describe the probability of a particle tunneling through a barrier.
